# How to properly redirect to js component and send information to db via php upon clicking submit?

Tags: javascript, php, database, reactjs, debugging

Currently I'm in `Login.php`.  Upon clicking `submit`, I'm getting redirected to `Home.js` with no problems but no information isn't being sent to the db.

However, if I do get rid of the redirection, then the data gets sent to the db with no problems but it won't re-direct me to `Home.js`.  Instead, it redirects me to `demo.php`

**Goal**:  How can I successfully get redirected to `Home.js` (which I am right now) and send data to the db simultaneously?

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's `Login.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from "./Home";

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            password: "",
            redirect: false
        };
        this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
    }

    submitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('json', JSON.stringify(this.state));

        fetch("http://localhost/demo_react/api/demo.php", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });

        this.setState({redirect: true})
    }

    render() {
        const go = this.state.redirect;

        if(go) return <Home/>;

        return (
                <form method="post">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="username">Email</label>
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            value={this.state.name}
                            type="text"
                            name="username"
                            onChange={e => this.setState({name: e.target.value})}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value})}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <button
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={e => this.submitForm(e)}
                        value="Login"
                        name={"submit"}>Submit
                    </button>

                </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Here's `demo.php`:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "loginapp");
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) ";
    $query .= " VALUES('$username', '$password')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if (!$result) {
        die("Query failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
    } else {
        echo "Data sent successfully to SQL";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is an asynchronous function, so the redirect is triggered while the form submission is still executing. You should probably set the redirect state after the response has been sent, so inside here:

```
}).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({redirect: true})
        });
```

And while you're at it, you should check React Router and its Redirect component. That's a better way of redirection.

// https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow